# wordpress tiny_mce not including paragraph tags - plugin dev

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to add an editor to my plugin and it works great except it strips out

tags.   This should, by default, include the P tags, no?

w

```
p_tiny_mce( false ,
        array(
            "editor_selector" => "content"
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `'wpautop' => true`, to your array?